# How to apply different line styles automatically to arrays in when plotting Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Is it possible to make Matlab to apply different line styles automatically as it does with colors when told to plot a higher dimension array?

For example:

```
plot(t,X1(:,4:6))
```

Creates a plot with three lines of different color. Can Matlab do the same thing with line styles? Even if it is something like:

```
plot(t,X1(:,4:6),{':','-','-*'})
```

I'd rather not have to go and call a plot command for each 1D array individually and assign a line style there if I can help it. I'm working with legacy code that has a ton of calls  without line styles already, each plotting a half dozen lines. It would take a while to do manually and I have to think Matlab can do something smarter

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in one command, but you still have to assign the style separately.

```
plot(t,X1(:,4),':',t,X1(:,5),'-',t,X1(:,6),'-*')
```

The other option you have is to write your own function that goes through a for loop and plots each one with different styles.